# Not able to loggin to fabric after installing in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter-fabric

Steps i performed:

1. Install Fabric plug-in in eclipse,
2. Restart Eclipse,
3. Click on Fabric icon from menu bar at the top of the eclipse.

Problem : Cursor is blinking at loggin user name & password (When Clicked through mouse) but not able to type anything on the fabric UI.

If anybody solved or having solution please reply.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing Java to 1.7 solves the issue.